# eBPF / XDP map not getting created

Tags: ebpf, bpf, xdp-bpf

I have an implementation in BPF for XDP, wherein I specify five maps to be created as follows:

```c
    struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") servers = {
        .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
        .key_size = sizeof(struct ip_key),
        .value_size = sizeof(struct dest_info),
        .max_entries = MAX_SERVERS,
    };
    
    struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") server_ips = {
        .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
        .key_size = sizeof(struct ip_key),
        .value_size = sizeof(struct server_ip_key),
        .max_entries = MAX_SERVERS,
    };
    
    struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") client_addrs = {
        .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
        .key_size = sizeof(struct port_key),
        .value_size = sizeof(struct client_port_addr),
        .max_entries = MAX_CLIENTS,
    };
    
    struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") stoc_port_maps = {
        .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
        .key_size = sizeof(struct port_key),
        .value_size = sizeof(struct port_map),
        .max_entries = MAX_FLOWS,
    };
    
    struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") ctos_port_maps = {
        .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
        .key_size = sizeof(struct port_key),
        .value_size = sizeof(struct port_map),
        .max_entries = MAX_FLOWS,
    };
```

However, no matter what I do, the `servers` map is not getting created. When I run `bpftool map show`, I only get such output as the following:

```sh
root@balancer:/xdp# bpftool map list  
68: hash  name client_addrs  flags 0x0
        key 8B  value 16B  max_entries 4096  memlock 98304B
69: hash  name ctos_port_maps  flags 0x0
        key 8B  value 20B  max_entries 4096  memlock 131072B
70: hash  name server_ips  flags 0x0
        key 8B  value 8B  max_entries 512  memlock 8192B
73: hash  name stoc_port_maps  flags 0x0
        key 8B  value 20B  max_entries 4096  memlock 131072B
74: array  name xdp_lb_k.rodata  flags 0x480
        key 4B  value 50B  max_entries 1  memlock 4096B
        frozen
root@balancer:/xdp#
```

It is notable that each of the key or value structs have been padded to the closest multiple of eight bytes, and there are no compile or verifier errors. I am also running the program on docker containers. So far, I have tried moving the `servers` map definition around in my code, commenting out the other map definitions leaving only the `servers` definition active, changing the name to other combinations, and a few other minor changes but nothing has worked so far.

Please let me know if you would need any other portion of my code or information for a better analysis of the situation.

---

**Appendix 1:**
I am compiling the object file using this Makefile rule:

```sh
xdp_lb_kern.o: xdp_lb_kern.c 
    clang -S \
        -target bpf \
        -D __BPF_TRACING__ \
        -I../../libbpf/src \
        -I../../custom-headers \
        -Wall \
        -Wno-unused-value \
        -Wno-pointer-sign \
        -Wno-compare-distinct-pointer-types \
        -O2 -emit-llvm -c -o ${@:.o=.ll} $<
    llc -march=bpf -filetype=obj -o $@ ${@:.o=.ll}
```

Then, in the container's environment, I load the program using this rule:

```sh
load_balancer:
    bpftool net detach xdpgeneric dev eth0
    rm -f /sys/fs/bpf/xdp_lb
    bpftool prog load xdp_lb_kern.o /sys/fs/bpf/xdp_lb
    bpftool net attach xdpgeneric pinned /sys/fs/bpf/xdp_lb dev eth0
```

The compilation process generates a `.o` and a `.ll` output file. The beginning lines of the `.ll` output file, where the map definitions are visible, are shown below:

```
; ModuleID = 'xdp_lb_kern.c'
source_filename = "xdp_lb_kern.c"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-p:64:64-i64:64-n32:64-S128"
target triple = "bpf"

%struct.bpf_map_def = type { i32, i32, i32, i32, i32 }
%struct.xdp_md = type { i32, i32, i32, i32, i32 }
%struct.ip_key = type { i32, i32 }
%struct.port_key = type { i16, [3 x i16] }
%struct.ethhdr = type { [6 x i8], [6 x i8], i16 }
%struct.iphdr = type { i8, i8, i16, i16, i16, i8, i8, i16, i32, i32 }

@servers = dso_local global %struct.bpf_map_def { i32 1, i32 8, i32 32, i32 512, i32 0 }, section "maps", align 4
@server_ips = dso_local global %struct.bpf_map_def { i32 1, i32 8, i32 8, i32 512, i32 0 }, section "maps", align 4
@client_addrs = dso_local global %struct.bpf_map_def { i32 1, i32 8, i32 16, i32 4096, i32 0 }, section "maps", align 4
@stoc_port_maps = dso_local global %struct.bpf_map_def { i32 1, i32 8, i32 20, i32 4096, i32 0 }, section "maps", align 4
@ctos_port_maps = dso_local global %struct.bpf_map_def { i32 1, i32 8, i32 20, i32 4096, i32 0 }, section "maps", align 4
@loadbal.____fmt = internal constant [24 x i8] c"balancer got something!\00", align 1
@_license = dso_local global [4 x i8] c"GPL\00", section "license", align 1
@process_packet.____fmt = internal constant [26 x i8] c"it's an ip packet from %x\00", align 1
@llvm.used = appending global [7 x i8*] [i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8], [4 x i8]* @_license, i32 0, i32 0), i8* bitcast (%struct.bpf_map_def* @client_addrs to i8*), i8* bitcast (%struct.bpf_map_def* @ctos_port_maps to i8*), i8* bitcast (i32 (%struct.xdp_md*)* @loadbal to i8*), i8* bitcast (%struct.bpf_map_def* @server_ips to i8*), i8* bitcast (%struct.bpf_map_def* @servers to i8*), i8* bitcast (%struct.bpf_map_def* @stoc_port_maps to i8*)], section "llvm.metadata"

; Function Attrs: nounwind
define dso_local i32 @loadbal(%struct.xdp_md* nocapture readonly %0) #0 section "xdp" {
  %2 = alloca %struct.ip_key, align 4
  %3 = alloca %struct.port_key, align 2
  %4 = alloca %struct.port_key, align 2
  %5 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.xdp_md, %struct.xdp_md* %0, i64 0, i32 1
  %6 = load i32, i32* %5, align 4, !tbaa !2
  %7 = zext i32 %6 to i64
  %8 = inttoptr i64 %7 to i8*
  %9 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.xdp_md, %struct.xdp_md* %0, i64 0, i32 0
  %10 = load i32, i32* %9, align 4, !tbaa !7
```

Comment: How are you compiling and loading the object file? Could you share that object file?

Comment: Dear @pchaigno , I added an appendix in response. Please see if this information is useful and let me know if you require further data.

Comment: Just checking, does your eBPF program use the `servers` map? Or could it be left aside because it is unused? Not sure how the program could load if it uses the map but it fails to create. `bpftool prog show` should show you the ids of the maps that your program uses, by the way

Comment: Dear @Qeole, yes, the map `servers` is used to hold the information of backend servers and is used once throughout the program by a `bpf_map_lookup_elem()` when a server is to be selected for a packet.

Comment: Dear @Qeole, I checked again after your heads-up and realized that the code branch that leads to where I have used the `servers` map is never reached by different combinations of variables in the program. Since fixing that raises another issue in my code, I cannot confirm right away that this was certainly the issue, but I will post the update as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes, if that's the case it's likely that clang detected the portion of code was unreachable and optimised it out. Then bpftool/libbpf looks for the maps that are actually used by your program, doesn't find it, and doesn't create that map. I hope you'll manage to confirm! :)

Comment: I mean you're definitely right. Thanks for your instructional comments. I got to learn quite a lot.

Comment: @Qeole Could you make your comments into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the discussion in the comments, **the map is not created because it is not actually used in your eBPF code** (not provided in the question).

As you realised yourself, the branch in your code that was calling the map was in fact unreachable. Based on that, it's likely that clang compiled out this portion of code, and that the map is not used in the resulting eBPF bytecode. When preparing to load your program, bpftool (libbpf) looks at what maps are necessary, and only creates the ones that are needed for your program. It may skip maps that are defined in the ELF file if no program uses them.

One hint here is that, if the program was effectively using the map, it [couldn't load successfully if the map was missing](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16/source/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L11813): given that your program loads, the map would necessarily be present if it was needed. Note that `bpftool prog show` will show you the ids of the maps used by a program.